# Deleting multiple sheets in multiple spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**1.**
I'm trying to delete multiple sheets in multiple spreadsheets. 
The code below works on 1 sheet but never moves to the next sheet.
I've edited another one of my scripts that did loop through all spreadsheets so I'm not sure where I'm wrong.

**2.**
My lastRow code gives an empty at the end and when I do lastRow-1 it doesn't show my last line.
My code, although it continues through this, bugs on the empty line. As the list gets updated from time to time with another script I can't set a fixed range here.

This code got a runtime error after running for half an hour.

```
function myFunction() {
  var dbsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ID Database");
  var IDList = dbsheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues(); 
  var lastRow = dbsheet.getLastRow();
//Looping through all the file ID's in the ID Database tab
  for (var i=0; i < lastRow; i++) {
  var destinationID = (IDList[i][0]);
//Locating the file
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationID); 
//Below the steps that will be executed
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
     switch(sheets[i].getSheetName()) {
     case "Asset List":
     case "History":
     case "Floorplans":
         break;
     default:
        ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm very new to java and scripts and I just trial and error with snippets of code trying to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the range to iterate starts in the 2nd row and not in the 1st, you need to subtract 1 to the `lastRow` variable to match with the length of the IDList array. The main problem is you're using the same `i` variable for both loops, you need to use a different counter variable for each, like `j` for the inner loop:

```
function myFunction() {
  var dbsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ID Database");
  var IDList = dbsheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues(); 
  var lastRow = dbsheet.getLastRow();

  //Looping through all the file ID's in the ID Database tab
  for (var i=0; i < lastRow - 1; i++) {
    var destinationID = (IDList[i][0]);
    //Locating the file
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationID); 
    //Below the steps that will be executed
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();

    for (var j = 0; j < sheets.length; j++) {
      switch(sheets[j].getSheetName()) {
        case "Asset List":
        case "History":
        case "Floorplans":
          break;
        default:
          ss.deleteSheet(sheets[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```